# Can an include file identify the calling page in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic, server-side-includes

I have 2 collections of asp files that are auto generated by a job.  Collection 1 has a virtual path of "/collection1/" and collection 2 has a virtual path of "/collection2/".  Both collections have the same asp code:

```
<!-- #include file="../SSI/Template.inc" -->
```

Inside Template.inc I have some typical html templating.  However, I'd like collection 1 to have a different template than template 2.  So my question, can my include file determine what page just called it so I can do a simple if statement and display a different template?

The easiest way may seem to change the job to render different asp, but this is not an option.

edit - I can add a handler for .inc to go to classicasp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say your collections are located in different virtual paths. So, you can check the URL of your page (using [server variables](http://neural.cs.nthu.edu.tw/jang/sandbox/asp/examples/request5.asp)) and render according to the path.

E.g. the following could be placed in the `../SSI/Template.inc`:

```
if instr(Request.ServerVariables("URL"), "/collection1") > -1 then
  'render html for collection 1
else
  'render for collection 2
end if
```